# How to know if WPF MediaElement is actually playing a video?

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I'm developing a WPF based application that must play some videos during its execution. To do this I was using the `MediaElement` class, however just after I made the first tests with my application, I discovered that some of the videos that I am trying to play are not supported by the Media Element class because I am missing the right codec. After the missing codecs were installed everything worked fine.

The problem is that my customer's machines can also be missing codecs, in that case I would like to display some kind of message saying that a codec is missing so that this problem can be solved quickly, however when I was looking at the `MediaElement` class I didn't find any property which states why a given video is not playing. Actually from what I've seen the `MediaElement` doesn't even throw an exception when the video that it's trying to play is not on the right format, nor does it has a state variable saying that it is or is not playing a video.

Therefore I would like to know if there is any way to discover programmatically at runtime if a given video can or cannot be played by the `MediaElement`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always subscribe to the `MediaFailed` and `MediaOpened` events. These two will execute on fails and on success respectively.

In case of a codec error `MediaElement.MediaFailed` will be raised.

Checkout [MSDN for more info on MediaFailed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed.aspx).

Comment: Hi, the `MediaFailed` event was just what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.